# USB 2.0 Frame SOF Collision

Tags: usb, driver, host

We are looking for possible reasons that a control transfer would begin so late in a frame that the device response would occur on top of the next `SOF`.  `wMaxPacketSize` is `0x40` (64 decimal).  We can rig the Host Controller Driver to hold off to next `SOF` when time is close; however we believe this to be the responsibility of the Host Controller.

We are open to thoughts and possible solutions.

Comment: Why are you looking for this trouble?  What is the ultimate goal?  Are you writing a Host Controller Driver?  I would think that host controllers and/or their drivers are designed to avoid this problem; they should know that the device is about to send (or is currently sending) a packet and thus avoid sending the SOF.

Comment: Yes, we have written our own host controller driver.  It is in production and works well.  However on the scope we have noticed events where the OUT packet occurs so late in the frame that the ACK from the device falls on top of the next SOF.  This is a rare occurrence.  We would assume the Host Controller would provide enough time margin to get the ACK before the SOF.  Is this true and if so, what other mechanisms are needed beyond the wMaxPacketSize setting in the EP?